# django model design - ManyToMany or ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am confused to take a decision whether to use ForeignKey or ManyToManyField.

Suppose I am building an application for an event which demands tickets to get access the event and delegates may get some coupon based on the category of the ticket they have taken. I might have the following classes:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    expired_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()


class CouponTicketMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(Ticket)


class CouponUserMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

- Organizer can map coupons to one or more tickets.
- Or/And he can map to some selected or random users.

(I do not need an extra field in the intermediate table that is why I did not use `through` here.)

I can redesign the `2nd`  and `3rd` model as

```
class CouponTicketMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    tickets = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)


class CouponUserMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I think I can achieve what I need from both design, but want get know about the consequences of both design. So which design will get more votes when considering aspects such as performance, storage, conventional style etc. Can anybody shed some light on making a decision.

Thanks

Comment: your two options are not functionally equivalent, so the consequences are irrelevant since one of them will not work.  bear in mind that a foreign key _can only hold one value_ while a many-to-many has _several values_

Comment: That I know. what I meant is that, I have these two options and I stated the situation where I am using this. I want to know which one is better for my situation.

Comment: you don't have two options currently: you have one option and something else that doesn't make sense

Comment: I think I could not make my point clearly. With both options (in CouponTicketMap model), I can  1. Check whether a coupon is assigned to  a particular ticket or not.  2. fetch all tickets who are eligible for a coupon. So which option is suitable for these operations. If I am opting Ist design, one extra table will come into action. I think that makes some difference in handling and storage also.

Comment: your first option doesn't makes sense as modelled currently, you should have `coupon = models.OneToOneField(Coupon)` instead... then a valid alternative option would be to eliminate the `CouponTicketMap` and `CouponUserMap` models and just have `ManyToManyField` directly on the `Coupon` model

Comment: I think ,coupon = models.OneToOneField(Coupon) will not be suitable in this case.

Comment: so you want each coupon to have multiple ticket maps? how do you know which one is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I´ll say this model due to what you say:

```
class CouponTicketMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    tickets = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)


class CouponUserMap(models.Model):
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Cuz, one coupone can have many tickets, and many users can have a related same coupon. Dont see neccesary to stick just to one parameter, when you can use them both depending of the designed needed. Hope my opinion helps.

Comment: Coupon can be also mapped to one or more tickets. So tickets = models.ManyToManyField(Ticket) is more appropriate, isn't it? Since it is one or more, this design is also sound good..